# How does ISP Automated Network Authentication Work?

Tags: networking, router, authentication, isp

My ISP (TalkTalk in UK) uses Automated Network Authentication rather than a password when I connect to the network.

How does this work?

If I switch to a modem that wasn't supplied by them, how do they authenticate me? Apparently they can still authenticate me without my MAC ID (at least it looks that way) so is it done through the physical location/connection i.e. my phone line and number (I realise it will be the ADSL/VDSL line rather than the actual phone line so it might have a different number on their system)?

Is this the same for all ISP's who use this method of authentication or does it vary?

Any good links for further reading on this?

All I've found seems to suggest that it is a combination of;

- MAC ID
- IP
- UserID

However, they won't know my MAC ID if I switch routers and they don't seem to say that I need me to notify them of it on the '[Set Up a Non-TalkTalk Router](https://community.talktalk.co.uk/t5/Articles/Set-up-a-non-TalkTalk-router/ta-p/2205383)' help page.

My IP is dynamic so that's out.

It can't just be on UserID alone... that's like having an account with your email address as your login and no password or authentication... anyone who knows your email address could login as you, especially when you consider TalkTalk UserID's are your phone number @talktalk.net and some people still have their phone numbers listed in a directory that is publicly accessible!

Comment: I think your ISP uses authentication by physical port. For example, each port on each switch within their network can be attached to unique VLAN...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about TalkTalk, but as far as ADSL goes – yes, since each customer has a dedicated point-to-point connection, the ISP's end (the DSLAM) knows exactly which line or circuit you're on and inserts that information into your router's DHCP requests passing through it. (You can search for the term "option 82".)

See also:

- https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/isg/configuration/xe-3s/isg-xe-3s-book/isg-auto-sub-logon.html

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed :) 

I have upvoted you but I don't have enough rep here for it to show (apparently it is logged but hidden)... I rarely post on here, I think I created the account to post an answer to a paricularly finicky problem and that was about it, usually I find answers here ;)